# How to set Top Layout Guide in Interface builder?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I found Top layout guide is not the same in two project but I do not know how to set the top layout guide in the interface builder, this will influence how I set constraints to other views.

In Figure 1 the top layout guide have 20 distance to the top(y=0).

In figure 2 the top layout guide is stick on top(y=0).

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Could it be because some of the views are embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: no, I do not use navigation controller at all

Comment: It depends on the Xcode version used to create the project, some versions added the Top Layout Guide and some of them don't

Answer (score 0):

In Figure 1: You can see constraint to `Top Layout Guide` and it will take `statusbar` as a base.

Whereas in Figure 2: You can see constraint to `SuperView` and it will overlap the `statusbar`

Comment: I see. So how to set Top layout guide constraint to superview? The pin in the bottom of Xcode can not do this

Answer (score 0):

Go to View Controller in interface Builder.
And Click Show the attributes inspector and then Select Status Bar as Defaults Both will be same.

Comment: do you mean simulated metrics set states bar "default"?  After I do this the top layout guide still have 20 to the top

Comment: if you dont want to see status bar then set it as "none".